# Histogram intersection or statistical test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

I want to compare two datasets that have the same dimensions and columns names.

My goal is to tell if the two datasets are "statistically speaking" similar or not.

These datasets contain both categorical and numerical data (also ordinal). In the deal between frequentist and bayesian, I would label myself more of the second kind, and I was trying to solve my problem with some code from the PYMC3 library (i prefer not to use classical statistical tests (k-s, t-test, and so on).

Anyway, while surfing the internet, I've found this method, "histogram intersection," of comparing two histograms, and it seems that it's been used in some computer vision stuff.

Is it ok if I use this method to try to answer my original question, or is it more robust to try to create a statistical test for each column in both datasets?

- here is a link to the histogram intersection method: http://blog.datadive.net/histogram-intersection-for-change-detection/
- here is a link to bayesian testing from PYMC3: https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/BEST.html

Thanks all

Comment: Exact *testing* for population equality is not at all the same thing as measuring how similar two things are (which is somewhere between estimation and a diagnostic depending on what you're doing with it). You should talk more about what this "similar" is that you want to identify. e.g. Why are you doing it? How were you conceiving similarity before finding the histogram overlap?

Comment: Yes, sorry. My goal is to find a way to say that these two datasets (validation set and test set in a machine learning project) are similar and not present distribution shift and similar problems. Histogram intersection returns a value,  that lies between 0 and 1. In this way if the value of this intersection is above a certain threshold I could say that "column A from validation test and column A from test set" (for example) are in a sort of way similar.

Comment: Until you define what you mean by "similar" (which relates to what you're doing with that) there's not much to be said; unfortunately your discussion above is essentially circular -- you start by talking about histograms being similar and end with talking about "columns" being similar but without any indication of what similarity is meant to establish in either case. What is this later 'similarity' needed to do, specifically?

Comment: An example. Two dataset with 100 records and 2 columns: age and profession. How can I say that the distributions of the data in these two datasets more or less similar? I think there'isnt a clear definition of similarity... In a frequestit way this should be done with a hypothesis testing by setting the p value, but I want to avoid this way. One way should be to check the histogram of the 2 columns (age and profession) and "see" of there is some overlapping, indicating a similarity

Comment: How would you use a p-value to determine that they are similar? // Are you familiar with Kruschke’s BEST methodology? The original BEST paper talks about showing similarity (“equivalence”).

Comment: On the contrary - a frequentist would not usually be inclined think that this is a suitable problem for testing (to the extent that I could be called a frequentist, I certainly would not). You should indeed want to "avoid this way", it doesn't appear to be suitable. Well, if you can define similarity sufficiently precisely you might indeed consider an equivalence test but I still don't think this is what you're after -- unfortunately you still don't explain (beyond circling back to using the same word) what you actually need this 'similarity' *to do* which makes it hard to suggest *anything*.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I need an indication of similarity between the distributions of the two datasets in order to say that the machine learning project can go on: there isn't in literature a "true" meaning of this "similarity". Following the aforementioned example, i have to say in some way that the values in the age column of the first dataset in close enough to the age column in the second dataset. This also should be done on profession columns, which are categorical. I'm trying to find one way that will tell me how much is this "close enough" .

Comment: Please do not give new information only in comments, edit 
 your question to add the new information. We want posts to 
 be self-contained, comments can be deleted, and anyhow, 
 information in comments are not well organized. Also, many 
 people do not read comments.